# Set debug mode to false during an automatic deployment of a django website

Tags: django

What is the expected process when one wants to deploy a django website automatically by means of a continuous integration process: how can we set debug mode to false without editing the configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally there are three very common approaches to switch between production and development environments in Django applications:

- Create a separate `settings.py` file with a different name and point to it using the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable. Once setting a value to it, the expected settings file within the project folder will be ignored.
- Use Python conditional statements to check for variables specific to your environment like `if settings.DEBUG:` and decide for other ones within that block of code.
- Make a `settings` directory inside the project folder and create three additional files; one for common settings variables like `common.py`, and another two for local and production specific variables such as `dev.py` and `prod.py`. You can specify your `__init__` to always import `common.py` and try to import one of the others if they are found.

Generally, you don't change anything in your code repository when deploying to production. It's the same code as on your local machine. The only difference is that your app server (gunicorn or uwsgi) is running with a different `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable.

Comment: The second bullet doesn't really answer the problem, since checking `if settings.DEBUG` requires a method to "flip" the DEBUG switch somehow. I'm using a combination of the first and third bullet: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE points to `settings.development` (file settings/development.py) on my local machine and to `settings.production` in production. Both import `settings/common.py` (so the other way round) and override or add certain settings specific to each environment. E.g database settings and email settings are different and inside `production.py`, `DEBUG = False`.

Comment: That means that basically you don't change any file in your repository when deploying. You only set your app server (gunicorn or uwsgi) to use your production.py settings file.